# What keeps accessing Google Cloud metadata on my instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metadata

I have a Google Cloud compute instance running with Ubuntu 18.  We had wireshark running tracking another problem and we noticed that every minute something is accessing the meta data server.  Three requests every minute:
GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/virtual-clock/drift-token?alt=json&last_etag=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&recursive=False&timeout_sec=60&wait_for_change=True
GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/?alt=json&last_etag=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&recursive=True&timeout_sec=60&wait_for_change=True
GET /computeMetadata/v1/?alt=json&last_etag=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&recursive=True&timeout_sec=77&wait_for_change=True

In call cases, the wireshark says the source is the IP of my instance, and the destination is the 169.254.169.254 which is the Google metadata server.

I don't have any code we have written that is accessing the server.  The first one makes me think that this is some Google specific software that is accessing the meta data?  But I haven't been able to prove that.  What is worrisome is that the response for the third one contains ssh keys.  Also, every minute seem excessive.

I see another post talking about scripts in /usr/share/google, but I don't have that directory.  I do see that google-fluent is installed. I also see a installed snap for google-cloud-sdk.  Could one of those be it?  I don't recall installing them, AFAIK, I am not using it, so if that is it, what is the harm in uninstalling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a problem to worry about. The metadata server is private to your instance. The Google VM guest environment software and Stackdriver (fluentd) are making requests to the metadata server to get credentials, detect changes (new SSH keys), set the clock, etc.

The IP address `169.254.169.254` is an [IPv4 Link Local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) Address. Only your VM has a route to that network.

[Compute Engine Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment)

Do not attempt to uninstall the Guest Environment. You can remove Stackdriver, but I do not recommend that. Stackdriver provides logging and monitoring features that are very useful.